# Button not click able with intellij automation java

Tags: java, css, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

iam on paypal page and i need to click agree button with automation

```html
<form id="ryiForm" class="proceed ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-class="{true: 'validated'}[validated]" ng-submit="confirm.$valid && onPay()" novalidate="novalidate" name="confirm">

    <!--         {@if cond="'{data.updated}' === 'bmlSuccess'" }         -->
    <!--         ngIf: merchantMsg         -->
    <div class="reviews ng-scope" ng-if="merchantMsg"></div>
    <!--         end ngIf: merchantMsg         -->
    <!--         ngIf: showShippingAddress         -->
    <div class="reviews"></div>
    <div class="offers"></div>
    <!--        inc/bmlLearnMore        -->
    <div></div>
    <!--        Action button         -->
    <!--         ngIf: showPaypalPolicies         -->
    <p class="paypalPoliciesLink disclaimer ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="showPaypalPolicies" data-ng-bind-html="htmlContent('memberReview.viewPaypalPolicies')"></p>
    <!--         end ngIf: showPaypalPolicies         -->
    <!--         checkoutSession.isRT need to review this         -->
    <!--         ngIf: showReviewLater         -->
    <!--         ngIf: checkoutSession.isAuthRequired         -->
    <!--         ngIf: showPolicyAgreement         -->
    <!--         ngIf: showFixedButton()         -->
    <div id="button" class="buttons reviewButton">
        <input id="confirmButtonTop" class="btn full confirmButton continueButton" type="submit" ng-click="setValidated()" value="Agree & Continue" track-submit=""></input>

    </div>
    <!-- ngIf: checkoutSession.plan.soft_descriptor -->
    <!-- ngIf: checkoutSession.displayBankChargeDisclaimer…   -->
    <!-- ngIf: checkoutAppData.flags.billing_address_conse…  -->
    <!-- ngIf: checkoutSession.plan.isAuthSignupEnabled ||…-->
    <!-- ngIf: checkoutAppData.flags.display_buyer_email_p… -->

</form>
```

from this page i need to click id=button. i used xpath,css,id all elements but its alwaysgive error " **Element is not clickable at point (353, 447). Other element would receive the click: ...**"

my code is

```
@FindBy(id="confirmButtonTop")
 public static WebElement agreeButton;
WebDriver driver;

public PaypalReviewPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

public void completePaypal() {
     agreeButton.click();
}
```

if some one have solution please help
thanks

Comment: Have you tried running this in different browsers? If you're using Chrome, [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=319) may be the root cause.

Comment: yes i have tried already but no success  any other suggestion

Comment: thanks guys its been solved

Comment: Would you mind posting how you achieved it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had just change small code

```
public boolean completePaypal() throws Exception {
try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    WebElement PayPalAgreeContinueBtn = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='confirmButtonTop']")));
    PayPalAgreeContinueBtn.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {

    return false;
}
```

}